# Getting the average of list inputs using Functions

Tags: python, function, sum, average

I'm supposed to design this program that gets multiple test scores for a student and store the scores in a list, drop the lowest score from the list, and then calculate the average score.
 When I run the code I get the error

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

```
def get_scores(grade):
    test_num = int(input('How many test scores do you want to enter: '))
    for t in range(test_num):
        print('Enter score for Test #', t+1, sep='')
        grade.append(input('Enter Score: '))
    return grade

def calculate_average(grade):
    grade.remove(min(grade))
    grade = (sum(grade))/len(grade)
    return grade

def show_results(grade):
    print('Average:', grade)

def main():
    scores = []
    get_scores(scores)
    calculate_average(scores)
    show_results(scores)


main()
```

Comment: sum on a list works only with numbers. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`input()` returns a string, not an integer. This means that `scores` has a bunch of strings in it, not integers, and you can't `sum()` a list of strings.

Change `grade.append(input('Enter Score: '))` to `grade.append(int(input('Enter Score: ')))`

edit: to fix the error mentioned in the comment, you need to change your main function:

```
def main():
    scores = []
    get_scores(scores)
    final_score = calculate_average(scores)
    show_results(final_score)
```

Comment: I've tried that before but instead of the error, it just shows the list without the minimum score but doesn't calculate the average